# How to access .so library from nodejs application

Tags: c, node.js, .so

I have a piece of C code which returns a string output.
The same api is packaged in the form of a .so file.

How can i use the .so file directly in my nodejs code.
Do i need to add something in my C code or there is a standard mechanism in node for the same..?

Thanks

Comment: Can't put it in an answer as I have never done it, but AFAIK there are 2 ways: 1.) write your own [node.js module](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) wrapping your [tag:c] API using [tag:c++] -- 2.) call directly using [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) (expensive at runtime).

Comment: Hi Ashish, Can you let me know how you got the solution for this issue?  I have similar task to be done my side.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What you can do is to write a C executable which uses the so library and returns an output. You can call this in your js file using the exec function.

```
exec('/<path_to_executable>/executable',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Should work, but forking a new process just for the sake of calling a function seems to be even more expensive than using [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi)